# Customising the colour scheme of the Core Location confirmation alert

Tags: iphone

I've got an app which uses the Core Location framework. I'd like to customise the colour of the popup which appears the first few times the user uses my app - the one which says "x Would Like To Use Your Current Location/Don't Allow/OK".

Does anyone know if it's possible to customise this to make it a different colour (the default background is blue, with white text) - and, if so, if Apple are likely to worry?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to customise the alert through the published APIs. There may be an undocumented API call to customise the alert (I haven't checked), or another sneaky way to do it (perhaps a category on `UIAlertView` to override `drawRect:`).

Beware, the App Store rejection team test that particular alert thoroughly, so an app that messes with it is likely to get caught.

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know. I guess there are lots of things that are technically possible, but not a good idea...